# View C++ output in terminal when executing Qt application (macOS)

Tags: c++, macos, qt, terminal

How can I view what the output of commands such as cout is in the terminal when executing an application?

For example, if I have an application named application.app, in order to run it from the terminal what I do is type `open application.app`

This launches the app correctly but I am unable to see the output of the print statements that are in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the program's `stdout` output in Terminal, you can run it instead like this:

```
./application.app/Contents/MacOS/application
```